# Output dynamic html in Ninja forms Mail

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

Is it possible to output a html string into a Ninja forms mail?

Situation:
A user can select some checkboxes and the values and names should each be wrapped in to a table row `<tr><td>Name</td><td>Value</td>` and should be outputted in a Ninja forms mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can add html to notification email. Switch to html editing by on this botton: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuUtQ.png
And then add the html you want to show in email like this:

```
<tr><td>Name</td><td>{field_name}</td>
<tr><td>Email</td><td>{field_email}</td>
<tr><td>Newsletter</td><td>{field_checkbox}</td>
```